# Java EE and Spring MVC "bootstrap" / run code at server start

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC 3.05.

I was wondering what the best way to create a bootstrap class was? Think Grails. 
In a previous project I believe another guy declared a spring bean and a schedueler but I also remember it was a bit ugly:

```
<bean id="bootstrap" class="com.jobs.Bootstrap" />

<task:scheduler id="SpringScheduele" />
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="SpringScheduele">
<task:scheduled ref="bootstrap" method="onServerStart" fixed-delay="5000000000" /
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

I believe this will make it fire at startup and then wait that time til it fires again. Not really ideal.

```
public class Bootstrap {

    public void onServerStart() {
        System.out.println("....");        
    }    
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create a bean implementing [ApplicationListener](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) and listening to [ContextRefreshedEvent](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextRefreshedEvent.html):

```
@Component
public class Bootstrap implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    @Override
    void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) 
        ...  
    }    
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go if you want to be sure all of the beans are created and initialized before bootstrapping.

Comment: Thanks. I am guessing all EJB and DB stuff will be loaded at that time?

Comment: Should it not be ApplicationContextEvent instead of the refreshed one? I just want it to run once at startup, I am guessing the other one will run it on code change and then publish..

Comment: Or perhaps it is ContextStartedEvent since ApplicationContextEvent is an abstract class...

Comment: ContextStartedEvent is not working, it does not fire... not sure why ... but the refresh one does!

Comment: Yes, the name is a little *strange*, but the correct one is ContextRefreshedEvent. I'm not sure about "all EJB and DB stuff": who starts EJB? Are there dependencies between EJB and Spring? What is DB stuff, connection DataSource? Maybe is better to ask some of them as new questions.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could create a class that implements `InitializingBean`, e.g. something like this:

```
public class Bootstrap implements InitializingBean {
    @Value("${my.prop.value}")
    Integer somePropValue;

    @Overrides
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        // runs after constructor & setter injection
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried that exact same example. But the method doesnt seem to fire. Do I need to do something else? Degine a bean ? I do have annotation-driven in a xml config file...

Comment: Add @Component to the class so component scan will instantiate the bean.